# How to make this global variable hold its value between calls?

Tags: node.js, rxdb

I'm trying to reduce the amount of times the database object is initialized in my data access file (variable `database` inside the file `tree-rxdb.mjs`). I created a global variable to hold a reference to the database object and check if it has been initialized before, if it has I just return the variable to the caller without initializing it again. For some reason, the `database` it's always undefined every time I call this function, even after I have successfully written to the database using the same code. Weirdly, the same doesn't happen to the `dao` variable inside `tree.mjs` even though I believe I'm giving it the same treatment but obviously getting differing results. I'm just emulating [this code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Node.js-Web-Development-Fourth-Edition/blob/master/Chapter07/notes/models/notes-level.mjs) but for some reason it's not working out for the `database` variable inside `tree-rxdb.mjs`, what am I not seeing?

tree-rxdb.mjs

```
import RxDB from 'rxdb';
import adapter from 'pouchdb-adapter-leveldb'
import leveldown from 'leveldown'
import Log from '../utils/log.mjs';
const TAG = 'fruits-rxdb'

RxDB.plugin(adapter)

var database;

const treeSchema = {
    title: 'fruits schema',
    description: 'Describes a fruits tree',
    version: 0,
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
        name: { type: 'string' },
        desc: { type: 'string' },
        url: { type: 'string' },
        state: { 
            type: 'integer',
            enum: [0, 1]
        },
        favorite: {
            type: 'boolean'
        },
        dateAdded: { type: 'string' },
        userId: { type: 'string' }
    }
}

async function connectDB() {
    Log.debug(`Database object = ${database}`, TAG)
    if (database) return database;
    database = await RxDB.create({
        name: 'fruitsdb',
        adapter: leveldown,
        password: (process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'myfruitsJsPasswordTemp')
    });
    await database.collection({
        name: 'trees',
        schema: treeSchema
    });
    Log.debug('Database has been initialized', TAG)
    return database;
}

export async function create(tree) {
    const db = await connectDB();
    db.trees.insert(tree.JSON);
}
```

tree.mjs

```
import util from 'util'
import logger from '../utils/log.mjs'
import Fruit from './Fruit.mjs'
const TAG = "tree-dao"

var dao;

async function model() {
    logger.debug(`DAO object = ${util.inspect(dao)}`, TAG)
    if(dao) return dao;
    dao = await import(`../dao/tree-${process.env.MODEL}`);
    logger.debug(`DAO model has been initialized: ${util.inspect(dao)}`, TAG);
    return dao;
}

export async function add(){
    const Fruit = new Fruit(undefined, 'Peach', 'peach 123',
        'http://something.com', 0, false, new Date().toISOString(), 'admin');
    (await model()).create(Fruit);
}
```

app.mjs

```
import express from 'express';
import logger from 'morgan'; 
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { default as fruits } from "./routes/fruits"
import * as tree from './models/tree.mjs'

const app = express();

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use("/fruits", fruits);

const add = async () => {
    await tree.add();
    await tree.add();
    await tree.add();
};
add();

export default app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing an `await` in `tree.mjs`. The line `(await model()).create(Fruit);` should be `await (await model()).create(Fruit);` the inner `await` was throwing me off. Now it's behaving like I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that database is only written when the promise of the creation is resolved. So calling connectDB multiple times will have database === undefined each time.

You should cache the creation-promise and return that from connectDB if it already exists.

Instead of

```
if (database) return database;
database = await RxDB.create({
    name: 'fruitsdb',
    adapter: leveldown,
    password: (process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'myfruitsJsPasswordTemp')
});
```

do

```
if (database) return await database;
database = RxDB.create({
    name: 'fruitsdb',
    adapter: leveldown,
    password: (process.env.DB_PASSWORD || 'myfruitsJsPasswordTemp')
});
```

Comment: I understand that but isn't the creation promise resolved after the first `await tree.add()` is executed in app.mjs? I can confirm that the data is being inserted into the database so I know that the database creation promise has been fulfilled by the time the second and third `await tree.add()` is executed. Why isn't `database` holding the result of the fulfilled promise after that first successful invocation of `await tree.add()`?

Answer (score -1):

In Node.js global scope is equal to the files' own scope. If you want to define a global variable accesible by all files at runtime, use [`global`](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/)

Comment: The variable is only being used inside the file it was declared in.